# Mac shared web folder permission on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I have my websites folder on Mac where I have created a `file sharing` with user `pi`. I have then created a mount to this folder on Raspberry Pi like this in `fstab`

```
//my-mac.local/Projects /home/pi/projects cifs username=pi,password=raspberry
```

This creates a mounted folder `projects` showing all the directories and files on pi. I can also run my php site using Apache from this folder. But the problem is I can't write into that folder. If I run `ls -l` command then it shows `root` user with permission `drwxr-xr-x`.

How can I put permission to make it writable by Apache webserver?

Comment: Add `uid=www-data,gid=www-data` to the mount command options.

Comment: I tried that also but it gives permission denied message

Comment: Also if I try to run `chown` or `chmod`, nothing gets changed in permission.

Comment: What userid gets the "permission denied" message? Use their uid=xxx and gid=xxx values on the mount command.

Comment: using PHP I have tested to create one file in directory and I get `fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/pi/projects/my-site/test.php`